# In what way can i debug this attribute error in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributeerror

I'm trying to follow a Regression tutorial for python as the stats model package does not seem to be working for me. So I got this far until I received an attribute error.

input:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("China_FDIGDP.csv")

data1 = data.dropna()
data1.to_csv("data1.csv", index = False)

Data  = pd.read_csv("data1.csv")

print(Data)

x = pd.Data["GDP"].values()
y = pd.Data["FDI_net_in"].values()
```

Here's the output:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "FDI.py", line 20, in <module>
>     x = pd.Data["GDP"].values()
>
> AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'Data'
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

```
Date    FDI_net_in          GDP 
0  1982  4.300000e+08  2.050897e+11
1  1983  6.360000e+08  2.306867e+11
2  1984  1.258000e+09  2.599465e+11
3  1985  1.659000e+09  3.094880e+11
4  1986  1.875000e+09  3.007581e+11
Index(['Date', 'FDI_net_in', 'GDP '], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Just drop the leading „pd.“ in your last two lines. Same way as you refer to Data in „print“.

Comment: KeyError: 'GDP' is the new error after following your advice. whats wrong with the GDP part ;/

Comment: Show a sample of your dataframe. You dataframe apparently don't have a column named `GDP`. Show the output of `print(Data.head())`. Also show the output of `print(Data.columns)`

Comment: try to do  print(list(Data))  and check column name is same as you are writing or not , sometime there are is tab space in column name and you can't see it.

Comment: Date    FDI_net_in          GDP 
0  1982  4.300000e+08  2.050897e+11
1  1983  6.360000e+08  2.306867e+11
2  1984  1.258000e+09  2.599465e+11
3  1985  1.659000e+09  3.094880e+11
4  1986  1.875000e+09  3.007581e+11
Index(['Date', 'FDI_net_in', 'GDP '], dtype='object')

Comment: @MoetMills   'GDP ' this is the name there is space , and you are trying 'GDP',   use this one 'GDP '

Comment: Random guesses: is `pd.Data` meant to be plain `Data` ? or `pd.DataFrame` ?

Comment: initially pd.Data but i've been corrected :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Data.columns = Data.columns.str.strip(' ') # remove tab spaces in column names 
x = Data["GDP"].values
y = Data["FDI_net_in"].values
```

Comment: Thanks alot! this worked. Why was there a tab space in the column name anyway? was it because i created the dataset in excel (where i had to clean it a little to get it to where i wanted)?

Comment: @MoetMills not sure about your data source its hard to tell what was the reason of spaces, but mostly when you change txt data to csv these spaces are common.

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from these lines

```
x = pd.Data["GDP"].values()
y = pd.Data["FDI_net_in"].values()
```

You have read the dataframe like `Data  = pd.read_csv("data1.csv")` so in order to get the `GDP` column from it you just want to access it like this:

```
x = Data["GDP"].values
y = Data["FDI_net_in"].values
```

Comment: I tried that and now i get this error: KeyError: 'GDP'

Answer (score 0):

Change the file name, if your file name is `pandas.py` or `pd.py` as it may cause some errors with the pandas library.

Comment: My file name is FDI.py so i dont think that has much to do with the error. im now getting KeyError: 'GDP'. any suggestions?

Comment: A Python `KeyError` exception is what is raised when you try to access a key that is NOT in a dictionary ( dict ). Python's official documentation says that the `KeyError is raised when a mapping key is accessed and isn't found in the mapping`.  Try Nickel's advice as mentioned in the comments of the original question above.